# Dijkstra first node visited

Tags: c++, printing, path, dijkstra

I'm implementing a Dijkstra program in C++ and I'm having some problems, let me explain:

For the moment I've been following this code:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

This code prints the full path from the source to all other vertexs.
I'm using an array int parent[num_vertexs]; to store the path. But the problem is that I don't want the full path, only the FIRST vertex visited.

How can I get only the first node visited? Is there any way to print only the first node of the parent array for each node?

Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: 
I'll show you my function to print the parent array, which contains the full path from a source vertex to all others.

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j){
// Base Case : If j is source
if (parent[j]==-1)
    return;

printPath(parent, parent[j]);

printf("%d ", j);
```

}

This function prints the full path, but I only want the first vertex of the path. The problem is that I dont know how to print only the first one for each vertex because the printf instruction prints the full path. Can u tell me how can I do it please? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there's a way. If you edit the relevant function into your question, we'll show you how to change it. (We don't like link-dependent questions here.)

Comment: Thank you Beta for your reply, I have edited the post. Could you please tell me what changes must I do in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is recursive; it invokes itself to print all of the path except the last vertex, then prints the last vertex. The simple, crude way to restrict it to printing the first vertex is to exclude the rest:

```
void printFirstStep(int parent[], int j){
  // Base Case : If j is source
  if (parent[j]==-1)
    return;

  printFirstStep(parent, parent[j]);

  if (parent[parent[j]]==-1)
    printf("%d ", j);
}
```

A better way is to change the code from recursive to iterative (that is, non-recursive):

```
void printFirstStep(int parent[], int j){
  // Base Case : If j is source
  if (parent[j]==-1)
    return;

  while(parent[parent[j]] != -1)
    j = parent[j];

    printf("%d ", j);
}
```

(It's not clear from your question that you understand the recursion. Please note that if you don't *understand* these functions, pasting them into your code won't do you much good.)